# Нужна ли здесь запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Что-то у меня уже совсем заскок. Кто-нибудь может объяснить постановку здесь этой запятой?

Из-за органически присущей фторполимерам низкой адгезии к любой поверхности, такие покрытия обладают низкой механической устойчивостью и сдираются с поверхности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, нет причин для обособления обстоятельства.